# Uncaught Reference Error: Excel is not defined

Tags: javascript, excel, ms-office, office-js, referenceerror

I am using the "JavaScript API for Office plugins" to create excel file in my HTML program.

However this returns an error message when I load the page.

```
<head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/Office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script>
    Excel.run(function (context) {     
      console.log('Your code goes here.');
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log('error: ' + error);
   });
  </script>
<head>
```

This returns an error message "Uncaught ReferenceError: Excel is not defined".

Comment: I am not exactly sure how to use this API. However, I saw in these docs that you need to wait for the `Office` to be initialized. There's this `Office.onReady` function and in the callback of this function I think you can perform the related tasks.
Here:   
https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/blob/master/docs/develop/understanding-the-javascript-api-for-office.md#initializing-your-add-in

Comment: Also I can see the warning in console `Warning: Office.js is loaded outside of Office client`, I think you need to load this inside an office client. You need to dig more as to what you're trying to achieve with this.

Answer (score 0):

Sivcan's comment is correct.  When an add-in loads, the API functionality is not immediately available (and often not even defined in JS variables), you need to wait until the the `Office.onReady` (or its older equivalent, `Office.initialize`) is called.

In your case, this should work:

```
<head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js></script>
   <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/Office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

   <script>
       Office.onReady(() => {
           Excel.run(function (context) {     
               console.log('Your code goes here.');
           }).catch(function (error) {
               console.log('error: ' + error);
           });
       });
   </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

Comment: Still, I am getting the same error. Please check this in [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/payuxehefo/edit?html,console,output)

Comment: Right.  This code would only work inside of an Excel Add-in, not just in a regular browser.

Comment: If you want a JSBin-like tool but for Office Add-ins, try https://aka.ms/script-lab